# how to save responsive menu open/close value?

Tags: php, html, css

We recently changed our front-end and start using Metronic responsive theme.

I have a left menu like:

[image]

Now since this is responsive if you click top left of the menu it resizes perfectly like this:

[image]

The problem is even if you resized it( for ex: small), when you click a link (or when page is refreshed), regardless of the size it automatically displays the big menu.

```
if (resize) {  use -> page-header-fixed page-sidebar-closed }  
else {   use ->page-header-fixed }
```

I know it must be something like that but how to implement this in php?

EDIT: I have an body class inside index.php like :

```
    </head>
    <body class="page-header-fixed">
    <?include "left.php"?>
```

left.php is the page that has the left menu. 
body class is the css class that I need to check

Comment: Nobody can figure out you problem with the amount of code you have pasted. Yes the images are very descriptive but since you tagged JS, php, HTML , CSS where is all that code?

Comment: if your php script always appends the same code in your html output the you should probably have to take a deeper look in your js/css files, Or post some more code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this setting **must** be stored on your database? If not, why not use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) and manage it with - and only - JavaScript?

I don't know your menu code, but if you can watch it open and close event, you can just use:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("menu", 1); // 1: open - 2: closed
```

Then on page load read it:

```
window.localStorage.getItem("menu");
```

No need to set ajax requests to the server nor cookies and that kind of crap.

Comment: Brilliant idea! Cheers

Answer (score 3):

In any case you need a variable to store the state of your menu i.e., big or small.

If you want to do it with PHP you can use session variables and use ajax to update that value when the menu is resized.

OR you can set a cookie with Javascript for the same purpose. I would go for this option.

Either way you will need to check the value of the cookie / session var and change the class of your menu depending on it.

---EDIT---

Or as our respectful fellow programmer says, it might be a good idea to use localStorage since the information doesn't need to be sent to the server.

Comment: Agree with this, session or cookies is a better faster option here. I don't see the need to update your PHP to handle this.

Answer (score 3):

You should perhaps add another js condition to test minimum offsetWidth before choosing css classes.

Otherwise, I wonder if you added responsive CSS `@media min-width` on both classes, `page-header-fixed page-sidebar-closed`.

If your JS doesn't overide these classes, CSS should do the job to keep your menu on "small size" look.